# SupportMapFragment is NULL

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, supportmapfragment

The method below creates the map to be displayed in the app fragment. But it is returning NULL.

axml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/mapGoolgle"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Activity File:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = base.OnCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

    initMap();

    return v;
}
private void initMap(){

    _mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) FragmentManager.FindFragmentById (Resource.Id.mapGoolgle);  //return null

    _googleMap = _mapFragment.Map;

    _googleMap.MyLocationEnabled = true;

    _googleMap.MapType = GoogleMap.MapTypeNormal;
}`
```

Comment: Did you set the correct permissions, API key correct?

Comment: It is not what the problem is. It his the way he is casting the object. Read the duplicate post... Even if the API key was incorrect, it would still work, however with a gray map.